Separability of LMI constraints
I have the following constraint:
$$
\Sigma \succeq A X A^\top,
$$
where $A$ is the decision variable that is also a lower-triangular matrix, and $X, \Sigma$ are both diagonal matrices. For example,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}, 
\quad 
X = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x_{22} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x_{33}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_{22} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sigma_{33}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Is there a way to formulate this constraint in a manner that would make it row-wise separable, column-wise separable, or both? I am following the following definition of separability for constraints:
A constraint set $\mathcal{P}$ is column-wise separable with respect to the partition $c = \{c_1, \ldots, c_p\}$ when $\mathbf{\Phi} \in \mathcal{P} \iff \mathbf{\Phi}(:, c_j) \in \mathcal{P}_j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, p$ is satisfied for some sets $\mathcal{P}_j$ for $j =1, \ldots, p$. Equivalently, $\mathcal{P}$ is row-wise separable with respect to the partition $r$ if $\mathbf{\Phi} \in \mathcal{P} \iff \mathbf{\Phi}(r_j, :) \in \mathcal{P}_j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, p$.
I am attempting to distribute this optimization problem using ADMM, so I would like this constraint to be separable. I attempted to write it as an LMI using the Schur complement,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & A X^{1/2} \\
(A X^{1/2})^\top & I
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
$$
Even though the constraint is now linear in $A$, this does not help. Does anyone have any ideas for how to make this constraint separable?
Thank you very much.

Are there some materials related to the context including the definition of separability for constraints?

The definition I included above combines definitions 2 and 4 from this paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05880. In section IV, partially separable SLS problems, they detail how they utilize the partial separability property to solve the problem using ADMM.
